# Regex find and replace for (AB), (AC), (DD), (OT)

Tags: regex

Is there a regex expression to find and replace any parentheses with two CAPITAL letters inside of it?

```
(AB)
(DD)
(OF)
(TO)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to find two caps inside of parens:

```
\([A-Z]{2}\)
```

Replacing them depends on the technology you are using.  In .NET you would look at the [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) method:

```
  string input = "some text";
  string pattern = @"\([A-Z]{2}\)";
  string replacement = "replace value";
  Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
  string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Answer (score 1):

In ruby syntax (see this live example: http://rubular.com/r/udlIIqLCLC):

```
\([A-Z]{2}\)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Perl syntax:

```
s/\([A-Z]{2}\)//g
```

This will replace any parentheses with two capital letters inside it with an empty string. If you want to replace them with some other string, just fill in the (empty) space between the last two slashes, e.g.

```
s/\([A-Z]{2}\)/replacement goes here/g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\([A-Z]{2}\)
```

will match your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it's rather quite simple:

```
s/\([A-Z][A-Z]\)/replacement/
```